# How to add pointers into a pointer to a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have this:

```
    std::vector<Pair *> *artistAttributes;
```

where `Pair` is a class, how can I add an element into this pointer?

I know how to access this if it was just a `std::vector` like so,

```
std::vector<Pair *> artistAttributes;
```

But I am unfamiliar with how to add elements into this since I am very new to pointers.

Comment: Instead of `artistAttributes` you just write `(*artistAttributes)` everywhere. And don't forget to make the pointer point to a valid location first.

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to a vector? It's not something you normally need.

Comment: "how can I add an element into this pointer?" - One does not add elements into pointers. One adds elements to containers - pointers *may point to* containers but the pointers themselves are just signs saying "that's the container over there", not the container itself.

Comment: `std::vector<Pair *> *artistAttributes` should probably be a `std::vector<Pair> artistAttributes`.

Comment: Assuming `artistAttributes` actually points at a valid `std::vector<Pair *>` and `p` is a pointer to an actual `Pair`, then `p` may be appended to `artistAttributes` in many ways, including `(*artistAttributes).push_back(p)` or `artistAttributes->push_back(p)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am very knew to pointers.

There is a semantic difference between pointers that just point to objects on the automatic-storage ("stack") and pointers to objects on the free-store ("heap") in that pointers to objects on the heap must at some point be used to deallocate (`delete`/`delete[]`) the memory earlier allocated with `new` (or `new[]`).

This is not just easily forgotten but cannot be done when an exception is thrown between allocation and deallocation. To make that simpler, smart pointers were invented which follow the [RAII/RDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)-idiom ("Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation/Resource Destruction is Deletion"): Raw pointers are encapsulated in Objects that manage the lifetime of the resource they handle.

This makes it possible in many circumstances to avoid following the [Rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (which is more a [Rule of the Big Four (and a half)](https://blog.feabhas.com/2015/01/the-rule-of-the-big-four-and-a-half-move-semantics-and-resource-management/) in modern C++) but use the [Rule of Zero](https://blog.feabhas.com/2015/01/the-rule-of-zero/) instead.

Also, there is no real point in having a pointer to a `std::vector<>` since vectors are cheap to copy (compared to the inconvenience of having to manage dynamically allocated memory).

So instead of

> ```
> std::vector<Pair *> *artistAttributes;
> ```

better use

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Pair>> artistAttributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
std::vector<Pair*> *artistAttributes;
artistAttributes = new std::vector<Pair*>;
artistAttributes->push_back(new Pair())
...
for(int i=0; i<artistAttributes->size(); i++)
   delete (*artistAttributes)[i] // Don't forget
delete artistAttributes; // Don't forget
```

In comparison to:

```
std::vector<Pair*> artistAttributes;
//artistAttributes = new std::vector<Pair*>; // no needed
artistAttributes.push_back(new Pair()) // use . instead of ->
...
for(int i=0; i<artistAttributes.size(); i++)
   delete artistAttributes[i] // Don't forget
```

and in comparison to:

```
std::vector<Pair> artistAttributes;
//artistAttributes = new std::vector<Pair*>; // no needed
artistAttributes.push_back(Pair())
```

Comment: compare to `std::vector<Pair> artistAttributes; artistAttributes.push_back(Pair());`

Comment: Also don't forget to delete all the `Pair` objects before you call `delete artistAttributes; `

Comment: Better: Don't forget to use a `std::shared_ptr<Pair>` instead of raw owning pointers.

Comment: and when `artistAttributes->push_back(new Pair())` throws, Houston has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you access a member of an object with the `.` operator. If you wanna access the member of a pointer to an object you use the `->` operator instead.

So you can modify the vector with `artistAttributes->push_back()` (to add a new element) or `artistAttributes->at()` (to modify an existing element). Equivalently you can also do `(*artistAttributes).push_back()` and `(*artistAttributes).at()`.